# Librerias integradas java

Tags: java

Recientemente comence a estudiar programación en java y hay librerias externas que debo importar para poder utilizar.

¿Cómo puedo instalar una libreria directamente a la raiz? Uso linux y encontré las librerias en `/usr/share/java` pero cuando copio ahi el archivo JAR e uso import no me funciona.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa el valor de la variable de ambiente LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Ya probaste a agregarlas a tu CLASSPATH? o a tu PATH?

Comment: es un manejador de dependencias muy facil de usar, asi te olvidas de estar manejando los jar de manera independiente . La verdad que te facilita la vida es una maravilla .

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisa [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio.